# Simple Spring Web App isn't working in Tomcat

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, tomcat

I'm currently learning Spring MVC and making a simple Hello World web application with it. However, I have no idea why its not working (The WebApplicationInitializer doesn't get invoked).

Here's the pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>springmvctest</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <name>springmvctest Maven Webapp</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>18</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>18</maven.compiler.target>
    <java.version>18</java.version>
    <lombok.version>1.18.24</lombok.version>
    <log4jdbc.log4j2.version>1.16</log4jdbc.log4j2.version>
    <rest.assured.version>2.3.3</rest.assured.version>

    <start-class>java.WebInit</start-class>

  </properties>

  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.4</version>
  </parent>


  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
      <version>5.0.1.RELEASE</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
  </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.12</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>${lombok.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bgee.log4jdbc-log4j2</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4jdbc-log4j2-jdbc4.1</artifactId>
        <version>${log4jdbc.log4j2.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jayway.restassured</groupId>
        <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
        <version>${rest.assured.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <finalName>springmvctest</finalName>

    <sourceDirectory> src/main/ </sourceDirectory>

    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>


          <plugin>
              <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
              <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
              <dependencies>
                  <dependency>
                      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                      <artifactId>springloaded</artifactId>
                      <version>${spring-loaded.version}</version>
                  </dependency>
              </dependencies>
          </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- see http://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_war_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.0</version>
          <configuration>
            <source>18</source>
            <target>18</target>
          </configuration>   
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.2.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

Here's the WebApplicationInitializer implementation:

```
package java;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletRegistration;

import org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet;

public class WebInit implements WebApplicationInitializer {
    
    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        context.register(WebConfig.class);
        context.setServletContext(servletContext);

        System.out.println("hi");
        // Create and register the DispatcherServlet
        DispatcherServlet servlet = new DispatcherServlet(context);

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic registration = servletContext.addServlet("app", servlet);
        registration.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        registration.addMapping("/");
    }

}
```

Here's the WebConfig:

```
package java;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("java")
public class WebConfig {
    
    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
 
        return viewResolver;
    }
}
```

And finally here's the Controller implementation:

```
package java;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class TestController {
    
    @RequestMapping(value =  "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String testMethod (Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("greeting", "Hello World 2");
        return "welcome";
    }
}
```

I have used clean install and run the .war on the Tomcat server

I tried entering 'http://localhost:8080/springmvctest/test' but it gave me a 404 error on the web, and no error in the output.

There are also no mentions of Spring in the output whatsoever, so I assume that Tomcat doesn't detect Spring ?

I'm using Tomcat 10.0.27 and VSCode as the text editor.

Comment: Why do you define versions for `spring-aop`, `rest-assured` etc instead of using the one which is provided by the spring boot parent? If you like to use more recent versions use the most recent version of spring boot instead???

Comment: @khmarbaise I think it's just a template in VSCode, I'm not too sure

Comment: (1) Spring Boot 2.x + Tomcat 9.x (2) Spring Boot 3.x + Tomcat 10.x + JDK 17 ; (3) Please use Tomcat 9.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Spring Boot framework will be written as follows

## Spring Boot 3

### Project Structure

```
├── pom.xml
└── src
    └── main
        ├── java
        │   └── com
        │       └── example
        │           └── springmvctest
        │               ├── DemoSpringbootJspApplication.java
        │               └── TestController.java
        ├── resources
        │   └── application.properties
        └── webapp
            ├── index.jsp
            └── WEB-INF
                └── views
                    └── welcome.jsp
```

### pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <!--<version>2.7.6</version>-->
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>springmvctest</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <name>springmvctest</name>
    <description>springmvctest</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
                <exclusions>
                          <exclusion>
                            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                          </exclusion>  
                </exclusions>                               
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
            <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

### DemoSpringbootJspApplication.java

```
package com.example.springmvctest;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoSpringbootJspApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(DemoSpringbootJspApplication.class);
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoSpringbootJspApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

### TestController.java

```
package com.example.springmvctest;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import java.util.Map;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class TestController {
    
    @RequestMapping(value =  "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String testMethod (Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("greeting", "Hello World 2");
        return "welcome";
    }
}
```

### application.properties

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/views/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

### welcome.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Welcome</title>
</head>
<%
// debug
System.out.println("webapp / WEB-INF / views / welcome.jsp ");
%>
<body>
   <h1 class="color-red">Wecome!  ${greeting} </h1>
</body>
</html>
```

## Package

```
mvn clean package
```

## Deploy and start

- Put traget/springmvctest.war to apache-tomcat-10.1.4/webapps/
- Startup tomcat

## Test

### Run Command

`curl http://localhost:8080/springmvctest/test`

### Result

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Welcome</title>
</head>

<body>
   <h1 class="color-red">Wecome!  Hello World 2 </h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Spring 2 / Spring 5 will not work on Tomcat 10, because Tomcat 10 is working with jakarta packages that are not present in Spring 2 / Spring 5, they are using javax packages. Either downgrade to Tomcat 9 or upgrade to Spring 3 / Spring 6 if you want to use Tomcat 10.